# DI: Different implementations of the same interface for the different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two controllers:

```
namespace V1
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        public SomeController(IProvider provider) { }
    }
}

namespace V2
{
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        public SomeController(IProvider provider) { }
    }
}
```

And the following services:

```
public interface IStorage { }
public interface IProvider { }
public class V1Storage : IStorage { }
public class V2Storage : IStorage { }
public class Provider : IProvider
{
    public Provider(IStorage storage) { }
}
```

For the first version of controller I need to use `V1Storage`, for the second - `V2Storage`. I know there is a way to replace `DefaultControllerFactory` but what is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [AddControllersAsServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvccorebuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to help with this. The documentation describes that this:

> Registers discovered controllers as services in the IServiceCollection.

Here's a complete example:

```
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddControllersAsServices();

    services.AddTransient(sp => new V1.SomeController(new Provider(new V1Storage())));
    services.AddTransient(sp => new V2.SomeController(new Provider(new V2Storage())));
}
```

By re-registering `V1.SomeController` and `V2.SomeController` after the call to `AddControllersAsServices`, you take control of exactly how they are constructed, passing in an `IProvider` implementation configured with the required `IStorage` implementation for each controller.

Andrew Lock describes this approach in [Controller activation and dependency injection in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://andrewlock.net/controller-activation-and-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-mvc/#the-servicebasedcontrolleractivator).